# How can I check if the value of a parameter passed to a javascript function is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code:

```
    function changeButtonState(targetSelector, action, iconClass) {
        var $target = $(targetSelector);
        var $targetSpan = $(targetSelector + ' span');
        $targetSpan.removeClass('sprite-blank').addClass(iconClass);
```

How can I make it so that the `$targetSpan.removeClass(..).addClass` only work if the iconClass has a 
value when the function is called. I guess what I am confused about is do I check if it is defined
or do I check if it has a length of 0 or more?

Comment: If you're not passing the parameter, it would be undefined, if you're passing it null, it would be null, if you're passing a jQuery selector, but have no matching elements in the DOM, it's length would be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best if you check for `undefined` as well.

```
function changeButtonState(targetSelector, action, iconClass) {    
    var $target = $(targetSelector);
    if (typeof iconClass !== "undefined" && iconClass) {
        var $targetSpan = $(targetSelector + ' span');
        $targetSpan.removeClass('sprite-blank').addClass(iconClass);
    }
}​
```

**Update**
Even though this is a very old answer, it is still relevant. Therefore, i would like to update my answer with an improved one based on @jeremy's comment.

```
function changeButtonState(targetSelector, action, iconClass) {    
    var $target = $(targetSelector);
    //this will not throw exception since iconClass is implicitly declared through the input parameter 
    if (iconClass) {
        var $targetSpan = $(targetSelector + ' span');
        $targetSpan.removeClass('sprite-blank').addClass(iconClass);
    }
}​
```

Comment: `undefined` is falsey, isn't it?

Comment: It will throw an `Uncaught ReferenceError` exception. Check the console on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plsoft/DgfhV/)

Answer (score 1):

This would allow the user (most likely you) to specify whether or not you want it to be active by either giving it a falsey value or a truthy value. You may also want to check if it's undefined by using the `typeof` operator.

```
if(iconClass) {
    $targetSpan.removeClass('sprite-blank').addClass(iconClass);
}
```

Comment: You mentioned I should do a check to see if it's undefined but then before said "just do a simple boolean check". Should I add undefined to your example?

Comment: I edited again. My original modification was due to comments in @jSang's post

Comment: Hello Nile. I think your post edit did not work as it looks the same. Should I check for undefined?

Comment: Hi Nile. Sorry I thought you were going to edit the solution thingy :-)

Comment: The reason I don't want to is because @jSang already has it checking against undefined. So depending on your uses, you may want to look at his answer also. I don't want to steal any rep or answers from him, so I'm deliberately not changing the example code in my answer out of respect =)

Comment: okay thanks. I understand. I upvoted you and accepted the other answer.